# prove that if $A\subseteq B$ and $C=B-A$ then $A=B-C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that  if $A\subseteq B$ and $C=B-A$ then $A=B-C$

To do this, take an element $x\in A$, such as $A\subseteq B$ then $x\in A \rightarrow x\in B$, i.e. $x\not\in A \lor x\in B$, from where $(x\not\in A \lor x\in B) \lor x\not\in B$ After this, try to work with the negation of a disjunction, in order to conclude that $x\in B \land x\not\in C$

However, it was not possible for me to achieve the expected result. Any help? thank you very much

Comment: From $x\in A$ and $x\in A\rightarrow x\in B$ you may conclude $x\in B$. You can then conclude $x\in A \wedge x\in B$. This gives $x\notin C$. So $x\in B\wedge x\notin C$. Thus $x\in B-C$. Hence $x\in A\rightarrow x\in B-C$. Now prove the other inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,

> if $C=B-A$, then $B-C=A\cap B$

This can be seen using a Venn diagram for example. In the OP, we also know that $A\subseteq B$, so $A\cap B=A$.

**Proof that $B-C=A\cap B$:**

$$B-C = B\cap C^c = B\cap (B\cap A^c)^c  = B\cap (B^c \cup A) = (B\cap B^c) \cup (B\cap A) = A\cap B$$

since $B$ and $B^c$ are disjoint.